# sorting an array of PFObjects by username

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I have an array of PFUsers and I'm trying to filter them based on local search results:

```
- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope
{
    NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate
                                    predicateWithFormat:@"username contains[cd] %@",
                                    searchText];

    _searchResults = [[_messages filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate] mutableCopy];
    NSLog(@"_searchResults: %@",_searchResults);
}
```

But this doesn't work and ends up producing the following error:

```
'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UITableView dataSource must return a cell from tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:'
```

Does anybody know what's wrong with my NSPredicate? Thank you!

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell;

    if (cell == nil) {
       cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        NSLog(@"here?");
        cell.textLabel.text = [_searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    } else {


        UILabel *name = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:101];
        if (_messages.count == 0)
            name.text = @"No Messages";
        else
            name.text = @"name";
    }

    return cell;
}
```

I don't think the NSPredicate filter is working though...

Comment: I guess it is not `NSPredicate` error, Can you show your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath` method?

Comment: You are not providing nearly enough information. You posted a block of code that filters an array into a results array. How does that relate to your table view data source? You need to provide a lot more information about what you're doing, and especially, post your cellForRowAtIndexPath method, as @Virussmca says.

Comment: try to `NSlog` the `_searchResults` array in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method and use _breakpoints_ to prevent app from crashing.

Comment: @GoGreen I am doing that and the _search results array never contains anything...

Comment: what about the same `_searchResults` array in `filterContentForSearchText:scope:` ? does it contain any value there?  If no, then are you sure you have a `user` with the same _character sequence_ as the `searchText` ?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is not with your NSPredicate but rather the fact that `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` is not returning a cell.

This block of code attempts to dequeue a reusable cell if the "cell" = nil. In this case a new cell is never actually created so attempting to dequeue an existing cell will always return nil.

```
  if (cell == nil) {
   cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
```

Instead you need to check if there is an existing cell available for reuse and if not create a new one.

```
cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
```